# Use virt-customize to copy file to boot partition of image

Tags: virtualization

Using [virt-customize](https://www.libguestfs.org/virt-customize.1.html) of [libguestfs](https://www.libguestfs.org/), I can copy a file from the host to the root partition of an image like this:

```
virt-customize -a 2023-02-21-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img --copy-in cmdline.txt:/boot/
```

But the image also has a boot partition (FAT) and I want to copy that file to that partition instead. Is that possible using libguestfs?